# 54321 4321 321 1 in Java

Tags: java

Hi everyone i need a java program to print:

```
54321
 4321
  321
   21
    1
```

I could get the numbers but am failing to understand how to space it like the above. Hope I could get some help. Thanks!

```
public class a
{
   public static void main()
   {
    for(int x=5;x>=1;x--)
    {
        for (int y=x;y>0;y--)
        System.out.print(y);
        System.out.println();
    }
   }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Thanks to @nickb i was able to get this.... 
This was the code i used for right-aligned spacing, just in case people in future need it for reference:

```
for(int space=5-x;space>0;space--)
System.out.print(" ");
```

Comment: **Hint 1 :** Maybe you should print some spaces before the number, don't you think ? **Hint 2 :** to know the length of what you print, you must convert it to a string.

Comment: yes but I am not able to do that... I have tried everything for the past hour and have been cracking my head on it.

Comment: A good advice! You honestly couldn't think of it @Anirudh?

Comment: @AltayMazlum i did think of that...

Comment: @Anirudh I gave you two hints. Closing this window and trying a couple other hours would be a good investment in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe you can use an array and let says remove some elements before printing it ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret thanks for your opinion..

Comment: @JFPicard i used this....for(int space=5-x;space>0;space--) System.out.print(" ");

Comment: *" ... just in case people in future need it for reference"* -  Given that anyone trying to solve a problem like this is obviously trying to learn to program, I think it would be doing them a disservice to provide a reference solution ... to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relationship between `x` in your code, and the number of spaces you need to print. Specifically, the number of spaces to print is:

```
spaces = 5 - x;
```

So, before you print the numbers, print that many spaces.

Comment: THANK YOU! I finally understood! this really helped me **thumbs up**

Comment: I can't seem to accept this answer for another 6 minutes for some reason.. I will surely accept it in a while! thanks